# Change the color of marker dynamically on Google Maps from JSON input

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to have three markers on the map but only one of them would be active, for example out of three markers only one of them would be green/purple to indicated the active one.

For example if I have this JSON object:

```
data =
    {[
    {
        "description": "Bombay Hospital",
        "lat": "18.9409388",
        "lng": "72.82819189999998",
        "title": "Hospital",
        "type": "Active"
    },
    {
        "description": "Lilavati Hospital",
        "lat": "19.0509488",
        "lng": "72.8285644",
        "title": "Hospital",
        "type": "Inactive"
    },
    {
        "description": "Aksa Beach",
        "lat": "19.1759668",
        "lng": "72.79504659999998",
        "title": "Beach",
        "type": "Inactive"
    }
]}
```

So if I do the lookup data["type"] and if it matches Active then make the marker blue, otherwise it is red by default.

I was looking into this for mapping multiple markers on the map: http://snippetrepo.com/snippets/multiple-markers-using-json-with-google-maps-api

Could you let me know how this could be done in a way that there is only one active marker with different color? The active one might change from Bombay Hospital to Aksa Beach and I would like to update this on map.

Best wishes,